# I have 16:00 in database I need to change into 4:00PM

Tags: ios, iphone

I have 24 hour time format. I need to convert into 12 Hour (AM PM) format please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use for it `NSDateFormatter` class and declare your date format

```
NSDateFormatter  *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"]; //AM/PM
NSString *formattedStr = [formatter stringFromDate:YOUR_DATE_FROM_DB];
NSLog(@"%@", formattedStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use following code for 12 hour format

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"US"];
[self.datePicker setLocale:locale];
```

you have to use following code for 24 hour format

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"NL"];
[self.datePicker setLocale:locale];
```